# How exactly does a Max 2 Sat reduce to a 3 Sat?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, satisfiability

Note: I've also asked this question on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100782/how-exactly-does-a-max-2-sat-reduce-to-a-3-sat)

I've been reading [this](http://web.stanford.edu/~rrwill/williams-max2sat-encyc.pdf) article which tries and explains how the max 2 sat problem is essentially a 3-sat problem and is NP-hard. 
However, if you see the article, I'm *not able to understand why*, after `ci` is satisfied, 7 out of 10 clauses are satisfied and if it is not satisfied, the 6 out of 10 clauses are satisfied.

Can someone explain to me in simple terms, and demystify what exactly the article wants to convey? Essentially, I have come to know that a max-2-sat problem is the same as a 3 sat problem. The question is I'm not able to understand why.

More formally, I wish to solve this problem:

> Consider the problem MAX2SAT described as follows.
>   Given a 2-CNF (Conjunctive Normal Form) Boolean expression  (with m
>   clauses, n variables) and an integer k, Decide if there is an
>   assignment satisfying at least ‘k’ of the total clauses? Compute the
>   complexity class (P or NP or NP Complete) of the MAX2SAT with
>   justification.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52473/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1633005/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the article is reducing 3SAT to Max2SAT (not Max2SAT to 3SAT).
In 3SAT, each clause has 3 variables and has the form $c_i=(l_1 \cup l_2 \cup l_3)$.

For each clause $c_i$, create the following 10 clauses:

$(l_1), (l_2), (l_3), (d_i), (\lnot l_1 \cup \lnot l_2), (\lnot l_2 \cup \lnot l_3), (\lnot l_1 \cup \lnot l_3), (l_1 \cup \lnot d_i), (l_2 \cup \lnot d_i), (l_3 \cup \lnot d_i)$

There are 8 possible truth assigments to $(l_1, l_2, l_3)$:
(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)

The assignment (0, 0, 0) will not satisfy $c_i$.
This assigment will not satisfy more than 6 clauses regardless of whether we assign $d_i=0$ or $d_i=1$
(try making the assignments to the variables to see for yourself).

The assignments (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0) and (1, 0, 0) will satisfy $c_i$
With $d_i=0$ it will satisfy exactly 7 of the 10 clauses

The remaining 4 assignments will satisfy $c_i$ and each of the assignments will satisfy exactly 7 of the 10 clauses regardless of whether we assign $d_i=0$ or $d_i=1$ (again try making the assignments to see for yourself).

So, given a 3-SAT formula with m clauses the reduction to Max2SAT is:

1) for each clause in the 3SAT formula $c_1, c_2,..., c_m$ create the corresponding 10 clauses.
$\;\;\;$So, we have 10m clauses for Max2SAT.

2) Any assignment that satisfies the 3SAT formula must satisfy all m clauses.
$\;\;\;$ Satisfying 1 clause in 3SAT satisfies exactly 7 clauses in the corresponding 10 clauses of 
$\;\;\;$Max2SAT.
$\;\;\;$Hence, satisfying all m clauses in 3SAT means satisfying exactly 7m clauses in Max2SAT.
$\;\;\;$So, set k = 7m in the Max2SAT problem.

So, since we know 3SAT is NP-Complete, this means that unless P = NP, that Max2SAT must also be NP-Complete.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nitpicking: even if it turns out that $P=NP$, Max2SAT will still be $NP$-complete. Only it will not be a very impressive feat, since every problem is NP-hard if $P=NP$. Also, this is not proven totally by the reduction, that proves its $NP$-hardness. But that Max2SAT is $NP$ too is trivial.

Comment: How are 7 satisfied in cases (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)?

Comment: @skim I've edited the answer and replaced $c_i$ with $d_i$. Hopefully this clarifies things.